# Quicksort implementation in C without using multiple arrays

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am trying to figure out how to implement quick sort without having to create extra arrays. Yet, this implementation only works when I use 1 as the pivot. The program seg faults when I use any other number. I cannot figure out which variable is getting out of bounds to cause the infinite loop. I would greatly appreciate any criticism/help on this function.

```
 void quick_sort(Item a[], int max, int pivot)
{
    int i, j, p, t;
    printf("%d", pivot);
    if (max < 2)
    {
        return;
    }
    p = a[pivot];
    printf("%d", p);
    for (i = 0, j = max-1;; i++, j--)
    {
        while (a[i] < p)
        {
            i++;
        }
        while (p < a[j])
        {
            j--;
        }
        if (i >= j)
        {
            break;
        }
        t = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = t;
    }
    quick_sort(a, i, pivot);
    quick_sort(a+i, max-i, pivot);
}
```

Comment: use the random function to pick the pivot from the available numbers at each stage of the sort. go check out the wikipedia pseudocode

Answer (score 0):

Your program is segfaulting because if you choose a hard pivot, like 2, for example, if `quick_sort` is called in a partition with only 2 items on the right of the array, `a[2]` will be out of bounds.

I think the best option for your solution is to choose the pivot inside the function, either randomly or just getting any arbitrary value, like `max/2`. You just have to be sure that `0 <= pivot < max`:

```
void quick_sort(int a[], int max)
{
    int pivot = max/2;
    int i, j, p, t;
    if (max < 2)
    {
        return;
    }
    p = a[pivot];
    for (i = 0, j = max-1;; i++, j--)
    {
        while (a[i] < p)
        {
            i++;
        }
        while (p < a[j])
        {
            j--;
        }
        if (i >= j)
        {
            break;
        }
        t = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = t;
    }
    quick_sort(a, i);
    quick_sort(a+i, max-i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in these two lines:

```
quick_sort(a, i, pivot);
quick_sort(a+i, max-i, pivot);
```

Quicksort works by recursively sorting smaller and smaller portions of the array.  Eventually, you get to the point where there is only one element in the array, which is the recursion base case.

The problem is that the `pivot` value is getting passed down through all of the calls as the array shrinks.  If the pivot is anything other than 1, you will **always** cause an overflow eventually (regardless of the size of the initial array).

The pivot needs to be selected *inside* the recursive function.